# React.js + asp.net core + windows integrated single sign-on

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, active-directory, authorization

I have react app which will be run inside company network, where authorization has to be done against active directory server (security groups are basically application roles and they have to control permissions in the application). All users of the application has windows computers logged into domain.

My idea is, that for authorization to work, I need only two information inside react frontend

1. windows username
2. list of security groups related to application in which the user is in

   (security groups might be admin, user, reporter, controller etc. and user might be in multiple of these)

Now I am trying to create custom `AuthorizationService`, where the idea is that I will read windows username from `httpContextAccessor` and when I have the username I am free to query active directory for information about security groups. This technique will also allow me to fake username and role combinations for testing and debug purpose.

but i face the problem how to get that information from `httpContextAccessor` ?

**My actual code**

**React App.js**

Before main react component is mounted, I want to get username and list of roles from the API and store it in the session or storage so that each component can read it and handle authorization if needed. (with sync and async issues I will deal later)

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.authenticate();
}

authenticate() {
   axios.get('/api/auth/sso', { withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.data);
       })
          .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
           });
}
```

**startup.cs**

I added windows authentication to startup (I believe these settings should include user info into access context accessor but I am not sure)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // => added
     services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // => added


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }
     else
     {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
     }

     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
     app.UseAuthentication(); // => added
```

**AuthController**

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

     public AuthController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
     {
         _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
     }

     [Route("api/auth/sso")]
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         // Get ClaimsPrincipal username
         // var user = this.User.Identity.Name;                              // => return null
         var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; // => return null

         var roles = new List<string>() { "admin", "user" };
         return Json(new { username, roles });
     }
 }
```

When I run the application, the `/api/auth/sso` is triggered, so I know my react code work's, but in the `AuthController`, I am not able to retrieve windows username from the `_httpContextAccessor` because `Identity.Name` is null and therefore I cannot start to query active directory :/

- What am I missing here ?
- What is good practice for this requirement ?
- Is this good way to go or I have to look into some different
  approach, like IdentityServer and JWT ?

Comment: Hello Muflix. Were you able to figure this out? I just bumped into the very same problem. Could you perhaps answer your question? Thanks

Comment: Hello @Biggles yes, I will. It was solved by enabling windows authentication in IIS (Kestrel does not have this feature) and after that `HttpContext` can be used for auth.